# Dijit Form isValid returns false while validate returns true after destroying a descendant

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I'm having a very strange problem  with a form done with `dijit 1.11.` in this case the form has a couple of `dijit/layout/ContentPane` in it, and the form itself is a `TabContainer`. Before submitting , based on a couple of rules a delete some of the panes, by calling `destroyRecursive` in it. Thing is, the form still does not submit.

Checking a bit further, the `validate()` method returns true but the isValid returns false, and that is the reason the submit does not fire. Checking the `isValid` method, what I found is that the `_descedents` property of the form was not cleaned of the widgets that were recursively destroyed when I destroyed the child pane. Some of theses widgets have the state as Incomplete, which makes the isValid return false (although validate returns true).

What is going on and how can I fix this?

Comment: Could you please post some code? Even better please consider creating a jsfiddle or similar where you reproduce your error. Thanks!

Comment: I will try to make a jsFiddle for it latter. We managed to solve the issue by calling the Form . connectChildren() after destroying the ContentPane, this  recreated the _descendants array and isValid stopped checking the wrong guys.

Comment: post your answere here so that it will help others too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to post a jsFiddle latter with a better explanation of the bug, but as a solution you need to call the Form `connectChildren()` method after destroying the ContentPane, this recreates the `_descendants` array, making the isValid function only check the existing elements